# Cannot access 14.04 using ssh/scp?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, scp

When I tried to access my ubuntu using ssh or scp from other OS, I cannot access, same as I put correctly password root. See the file below

If I use ssh appear the same problem...

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The root account has no password and is locked by default.  You need to log in as your regular account, and then use `sudo` if you need root access.

Comment: @psusi I have alrady use this command $ sudo passwd root but nothing change

Comment: I've seen you  have used `-p` without specifying a port. I don't think this is legal

Comment: @LukeMadhanga Even I use #ssh root@hostname I can't access my ubuntu

Comment: @VitorMazuco: That's because you *can't* (well, shouldn't) log into the `root` account. Log into *your* user account.

Comment: @LukeMadhanga: In `scp`, `-P` specifies the port number; `-p` is to preserve modification and access times.

Comment: @saiarcot895 awkward :v I always get confused with scp and ssh when it comes to declaring the port

Comment: @LukeMadhanga: I just generalize it as "if it's not `ssh`, it's `-P`," since I've seen the same syntax on a few other programs.

Comment: Use a non-root account to login. If you don't have one yet, you need to login to your server (non-remotely) and create one. You can then login with that user. You can also add the created user to the sudoers list so that you can switch to root after logging in.

Comment: I also found [this link](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/V2V_Guide/Preperation_Before_the_P2V_Migration-Enable_Root_Login_over_SSH.html) that might help. It is tailored for red hat but it should probably work for Ubuntu to and maybe solve your problem.

Comment: @MichaelAquilina All right Michael! Thanks so much!

Comment: Done. I placed information for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging in with a root user via ssh is disabled by default. You can login with non-root user and then run `su` or `sudo` to run commands with root privileges.

Take a look at [this link](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/V2V_Guide/Preperation_Before_the_P2V_Migration-Enable_Root_Login_over_SSH.html) which explains how to enable root logins if that is something you want. The page itself is tailored for red hat but you shouldn't have any problems getting the same solution to work for Ubuntu 14.04.